# Is This Wave Equation Solvable with the Given Boundary Conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The wave equation is the usual $u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} = 0$.  We are only considering $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le t \le 1$.  Here are the boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
u(x, 0) = f(x) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, & u(x, 1) = g(x) \\
u(0, t) = h(t) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, & u(1, t) = k(t) 
\end{align}
In the above, $f, g, h, k$ are continuously differentiable.  From the derivation of d'Alembert's solution, we know that, to find the solution, we need the full set of the first-order derivative along one side of the square.  For example:
\begin{align}
u_x(x, 0) = f(x) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, u_t(x, 0) = ???
\end{align}
So potentially, there is no solution here.

On the other hand, given a set of boundary conditions, it is necessary for them to be compatible.  For example:
\begin{align}
u(x, y) & = f(x, y) \\
u_x(x, y) & = \phi(x, y) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \rightarrow \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \frac{du}{dx} = u_x + u_y \frac{dy}{dx}\\
u_t(x, y) & = \eta(x, y) \\
\end{align}
So, from the above, we need something like $f_x(x, y) = \phi(x, y) + \eta(x, y)\frac{dy}{dx}$.  I would like to construct a counter-example that fails compatibility.  Would you be able to help?

Comment: Are you talking about 2D or 1D in space?  And why is $u_t(x,0) \ne 0$?

Comment: This is 2D, and the question is what happens when you don't have $u_t(x, 0)$.

Comment: Hint: Write the wave equation as a first order system. How many initial conditions and boundary conditions do you need for each PDE?